# Changing colors in cells when I change the cell of column 5, he doesn't stop here, he change the next cell

Tags: java, swing, colors, tablecellrenderer

I have a problem with changing colors in cells, when I change the cell of column 5, he doesn't stop here, he change the next cell...
Here is my code :

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        Etudiant E = new Etudiant();

        if (column == 0) {
            int id = E.getAIdEtud(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString(), table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
            if (E.IsRoudoublan(id) && E.IsExcclu(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
            } else if (E.IsExcclu(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
            } else if (E.IsRoudoublan(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(20, 200, 0));
            }
        } else if (column == 5) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString()) >= 3) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(20, 200, 20));
            }
        } else {
            c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
        }

        return c;

    }
}
```

Comment: The row/columns reported in `getTableCellRendererComponent` are view indexes. You are using these to look up values in the model. Use the `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel` and `JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel` to get the associated model index to use to look up the values in the model...

Comment: Also, in the part for `column == 5` you need to add an `else` part to set the color for the case where the string is < 3

Comment: I tried this option, but it didn't work

Comment: `I tried this option, but it didn't work` - then your code is wrong. Try again. Also, your renderer should not be checking the column. Instead you should create 2 separate renderers. Then you can add each renderer to a specific column. This will simplify the if/else logic making it easier to spot your error.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your snippet and corrected all problems that I found. Check for all lines with comments.

Notes:

- Provide a color for all possible code paths, you forgot to provide a color in two spots (see  the `// << provide ELSE part here, eg:` lines)
- Indexes reported in the [`TableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent%28javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int%29) method are view indexes.
- When indexing the model, you need to use model indexes. You are using view indexes to index the model. That can lead to problems e.g. when your table is sorted, when you rearrange columns or when you apply a row filter. Look for the lines with comments at the end for corrections.

---

```java
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int rowViewId, int columnViewId) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, rowViewId, columnViewId);
        Etudiant E = new Etudiant();

        int rowModelId = table.convertRowIndexToModel(rowViewId); // << for lookup of values in the model
        int colModelId = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(columnViewId); // << for lookup of values in the model

        if (colModelId == 0) { // << you mean to check if the model index is 0 here
            int id = E.getAIdEtud(table.getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 1).toString(), table.getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 2).toString()); // << when indexing the model, use model indexes
            if (E.IsRoudoublan(id) && E.IsExcclu(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
            } else if (E.IsExcclu(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
            } else if (E.IsRoudoublan(id)) {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(20, 200, 0));
            }
            // << provide ELSE part here, eg:
            else {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
            }
        } else if (colModelId == 5) { // << you mean to check if the model index is 5 here
            if (Integer.parseInt(table.getModel().getValueAt(rowModelId, 5).toString()) >= 3) { // << when indexing the model, use model indexes
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(20, 200, 20));
            }
            // << provide ELSE part here, eg:
            else {
                c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
            }
        } else {
            c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```